# Expression to include by file name but exclude by same folder name

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio-2012, mstest, code-coverage

I'm trying to figure out how to configure VS Code Coverage Run Settings to include only target libraries but not test libraries and not 3rd party libraries:

Syntax is the following:

```
<Include>
    <ModulePath>.*\\MyProject\..*\.dll$</ModulePath>
</Include>
<Exclude>
    <ModulePath>.*\.Test.dll$</ModulePath>
</Exclude>
```

String inside is a full path (look like), e.g.:

```
...\Projects\MyProject\trunk\MyProject.Data\bin\Debug\MyProject.Data.dll
...\Projects\MyProject\trunk\MyProject.Data\bin\Debug\MyProject.Data.Test.dll
...\Projects\MyProject\trunk\MyProject.Data\bin\Debug\Moq.dll
```

My include RegEx so far causes to include both target dll and 3rd party dll.

How to include

```
...\Projects\MyProject\trunk\MyProject.Data\bin\Debug\MyProject.Data.dll
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

but exclude

```
...\Projects\MyProject\trunk\MyProject.Data\bin\Debug\Moq.dll
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code Coverage only loads assemblies for which there are .pdb files. So the easiest solution should actually be to remove the .pdb files for your external libraries. You are not very likely to debug inside those, anyway.

Comment: But 3rd pdb file is coming with NuGet package restored (loaded) automatically. Also by documentation 3rd party libs should not be loaded anyway if Include is missing/empty. But in fact they are loaded.

Comment: Then you should explicitly exclude your dependencies instead of explicitly including only that which you do want covered. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx

Comment: I don't want to list all files to exclude (let's leave this option as a workaround) but want to have one expression instead.

Comment: I realise that. I am just sceptical if that is doable.

Comment: I'm no so good in Regex, spent a day trying to figure out, then decided to ask on SO. If that's really not doable, will give up and use your solution.

Comment: Sorry. Wish I could help you more.